# Always On Availability Group ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly Not routing to Secondary

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups

Version: SQL 2012 SP3
Two Node. 1 Primary 1 Secondary

This is how nodes are set up.

[image]

Using SSMS connection options when I set connection property `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly` I am not getting routed to secondary node. Yes I am using listener name as Server name.

[image]

I did not create any read-only routing list because I only have 2 nodes.

**Question 1**

Am I wrong that even with only 2 nodes I need read-only routing list?

**Question 2**

What is the difference between these 2 settings about `Readable Secondary`? Secondaries can only serve read-only traffic, so why route other connections with selecting `Yes`?

As per [books online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-read-only-access-on-an-availability-replica-sql-server):

> Read-intent only
>
> Only read-only connections are allowed to secondary databases of this
>   replica. The secondary database(s) are all available for read access.
>
> Yes
>
> All connections are allowed to secondary databases of this replica,
>   but only for read access. The secondary database(s) are all available
>   for read access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have a read-routing list, even with only two instances, if you want to offload reads to a secondary replica.

The following script is an example of setting this up (you would change the AG name to whatever your AG is, and the replicas to your servernames (using the fully qualified domain name, and adjusting the port if required).

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP YOURAGNAME MODIFY REPLICA ON 'REPLICA1' with (SECONDARY_ROLE (READ_ONLY_ROUTING_URL = N'TCP://REPLICA1.FQDN:1433'));
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP YOURAGNAME MODIFY REPLICA ON 'REPLICA2' with (SECONDARY_ROLE (READ_ONLY_ROUTING_URL = N'TCP://REPLICA2.FQDN:1433'));

ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP YOURAGNAME MODIFY REPLICA ON 'REPLICA1' with (PRIMARY_ROLE (READ_ONLY_ROUTING_LIST = ('REPLICA2', 'REPLICA1')));
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP YOURAGNAME MODIFY REPLICA ON 'REPLICA2' with (PRIMARY_ROLE (READ_ONLY_ROUTING_LIST = ('REPLICA1', 'REPLICA2')));
```

As regards the flags:

- ReadIntent allows for connections only passed along with the
  ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly flag
- Yes allows for any connection to the
  database (meaning you could connect directly with SSMS and run
  queries)

Comment: on `Yes` allows me to connect with SSMS using secondary SQL server name? I can do the same even when it set to `read-intent`.

Comment: `Yes` would allow you to connect directly to the secondary replica, into the database, and give you the chance to query things as you normally would. The `readintent` would require you to pass along the applicationintent information in order to connect. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/about-client-connection-access-to-availability-replicas-sql-server does a fairly good job of explaining it.

Comment: Thanks again. I am still confused because with `readintent` I can connect to a secondary node using server name in SSMS which I expect to. Then I can browse the database in AG and query the content.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide I suspect this is the case because you're connecting with a privileged account.  Try this using a SQL Login with limited permissions to the database and see what happens.